# directory foreach extension powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, directory

I need to check a folder and make an array of all the different extensions
(and this part goes wel)

```
$dir = dir C:\Users\seppe\Desktop\School\Scripting\Lab06\scripting_Lab06_opdr3 | Group-Object -property extension | Format-Table -Property Name
```

now here is the problem: with this array i need to make a foreach to make different folders. The folder names need to be the different types of files (like: doc. I have this:

```
foreach($_ in $dir ){
mkdir C:\Users\seppe\Desktop\School\Scripting\Lab06\scripting_Lab06_opdr3\$_
}
```

But I get 5 (and in my case i only need 3(because ther are 3 types of documents in the folder)) folders but whit this names:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are always several powershell ways:

```
cd "C:\Users\seppe\Desktop\School\Scripting\Lab06\scripting_Lab06_opdr3\"
$Extensions = (dir . -file | %{$_.Extension} | Sort -unique).Trimstart(".")
$Extensions | %{If (!(Test-Path $_)){MD $_}}
```

Comment: This is indeed a bit more accurate because now i have a dir PNG instead of .PNG

Answer (score 0):

You either need to specify the `Name` property of the $_ object when you create the folder (as this contains the extension)

```
mkdir C:\Users\seppe\Desktop\School\Scripting\Lab06\scripting_Lab06_opdr3\$_.Name
```

Or select only the extensions when you create the array to start with:

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\seppe\Desktop\School\Scripting\Lab06\scripting_Lab06_opdr3 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extension
```

Comment: Then i get the same output but with .name at the end

Comment: Change it to `$($_.Name)` instead, or try the second option that I added.

Comment: Found the problem because of you thanks, the moment i do a group-object then it doesnt work anymore! so i will get errors for dupplicated names but it will work thanks!

Comment: `Group-Object` doesn't remove duplicates, but `Select-Object` can - which is what my update added to my answer.